# Trapping a Twisted "Unhandled error in Deferred:" but it is in someone else's code

Tags: python-3.x, deferred, twisted.internet

I am using a module from someone else to handle listening to a websocket.

As part of my testing I found that a simulated internet outage (by disabling/enabling my internet adapter) causes twisted.deferred to throw an error that doesn't get trapped by my exception handling.
It appear that it just prints the error message, instead of passing it on?

The problem is that then I cannot get it to gracefully handle it (e.g. keep checking the internet connection and resume processes when it is back up).

Is there anyway that I can 'listen' for such errors and trap them myself, or do I need to climb the tree and recode the other persons work?

I also use the signal module to catch 'Keyboard interrupt signal received' for manually stopping execution (not shown for brevity).

```
conn.start()

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as err:
        # Stop streams and logging gracefully
        Print('Some other Exception received: ' + err)
        conn.close()
        user_log.close()
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Ok, so looking at the websocket code, it passes the error message as a callback, which is received by my code as a message. The weird thing is it occasionally passes a structured error message in JSON format (which my logging code diligently logs), but if it throws an error then reading the message causes the error to trigger an error, which I can trap as an exception. 
Then the remaining trick is getting it to exit() from within an exception...

Comment: Hmm, so I can trap the error without an exception (it passes a dictionary as normal payload but my multiplex handler was not set to handle non-multiplex data), but when it gets to the line to execute sys.exit() the Deferred thread is still running, even though I close the websocket manager = untrapped error in Deferred that is outside of __main__ and won't exit....

Comment: Ok, so where defer.py for twisted is falling over is so deep in nested try..except.. layers that I can't figure it out...

Comment: __main__  imports SocketManager which imports twisted and threading.
But SocketManager's close() function can't stop twisted.defer from catching the exception in _runCallbacks() in the deep nested try...except.. when it gets passed back through the tangle of twisted.internet ping pong between tcp, defer, base, _resolver, policies.
Surely this is a common problem with twisted running when the internet goes down?

Comment: So for now, I'm ejecting the core so it can explode in the depths of space... Once I handle it to shut down my logging, etc
```
os._exit()
```